# Accessing items in nested dicts and lists in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

Data:

```
primaries:
  ca:
    - 10.51.60.45 
    - 10.51.60.46 
  ny:
    - 10.52.60.45 
    - 10.52.60.46
  az:
    - 10.53.60.45
    - 10.53.60.46
```

I want a flattened list of all IP's(or a for loop which can iterate through just the IP's), but the cities `ca` and `ny` and `az` could be anything.

Comment: In what context are you using Jinja2? If you're using it in Python it would be much easier to flatten the lists in Python, and if you're using Ansible, there are filters available that would make this easier as well.

Comment: In a template in Ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible's [extract filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables), which extracts the value of a key from a container, makes this very simple.

```
{{ primaries | map('extract', primaries) | flatten }}
```

You can also directly use the dictionary's `values()` method, which is slightly less flexible (the `extract` approach allows you to filter the keys beforehand, which you can't do here.)

```
{{ primaries.values() | flatten }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through the keys of the dictionary.

```
{% for region, ips in primaries.items() %}
  {% for ip in ips %}
    {{ ip }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Read the Jinja docs on [for](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for).

Answer (score 0):

Using Ansible, you can get a flattened list of ips using the `json_query` filter:

```
List of ip addresses:
{% for addr in primaries|json_query('*[][]') %}
- {{ addr }}
{% endfor %}
```

This results in:

```
List of ip addresses:
- 10.51.60.45
- 10.51.60.46
- 10.52.60.45
- 10.52.60.46
- 10.53.60.45
- 10.53.60.46
```

Here's a runnable example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    primaries:
      ca:
        - 10.51.60.45 
        - 10.51.60.46 
      ny:
        - 10.52.60.45 
        - 10.52.60.46
      az:
        - 10.53.60.45
        - 10.53.60.46
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest:  addresses.txt
        content: |
          List of ip addresses:
          {% for addr in primaries|json_query('*[][]') %}
          - {{ addr }}
          {% endfor %}
```

The `json_query` filter uses the [JMESPath query language](https://jmespath.org/).